# What is the wavelength of a hot metal when its temperature 400 C?

Tags: temperature, thermal-radiation, wavelength

I would like to know what will be the wavelength of a hot steel which temperature is 400 degree C

Comment: Steel is a wave! Nobel prize for 2016 is his;}

Comment: @user36790 shouldn't that one go to De Broglie?

Comment: @Asher; No; De-Broglie wave though exists for a metal steel bar but the wavelength is infinitesimally negligible to be considered. I could understand what OP wanted to tell; he was telling about radiation. But in order to clear his query, I intended to mock him;)

Comment: The question in its current form makes no sense. You must be asking for the maximum intensity wavelength.

Comment: Seriously guys, this is unlcear? Have you never heard of the [*Wien's displacement*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien%27s_displacement_law)?

Comment: I don't think this is unclear - it's asking about blackbody radiation - but it's off topic because it is a homework question.

Comment: @HDE226868 where in the question is a "black body" mentioned? I see a question asking about "metal" or "steel" depending on whether you read the title or the question body. Neither of those is a black body.

Comment: @DanielSank See [Floris's comment](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/200847/what-is-the-wavelength-of-a-hot-metal-when-its-temperature-400-c?noredirect=1#comment428113_200855). A black body approximation should be fine.

Comment: @HDE226868 Floris's comment [begs the question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beg_a_question).

Comment: Thanks John Rennie for your answer with relevant data which is very useful to calculate the wavelength.

Comment: @RavikumarV - if you think that John's answer was useful, it is customary to mark it "accepted" with the little check mark that sits to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

To a good approximation the radiation emitted from a hot piece of steel will be the same as emitted by a [black body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_body). The relationship between the wavelength $\lambda$ of light emitted by a black body and the temperature $T$ is given by [Planck's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law):

$$ B = \frac{2hc^2}{\lambda^5} \frac{1}{e^{hc/\lambda k_b T} - 1} $$

where $B$ is the [spectral radiance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiance), $h$ is Planck's constant, $c$ is the speed of light, and $k_b$ is the Boltzmann constant.

So if you feed in $T = 673$K you can calculate the wavelength distribution of the light emitted. Note that the steel emits a range of wavelengths not a single wavelength. If you just want the peak wavelength, i.e. the wavelength at which most light is emitted, then  this is given by [Wien's displacement law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien%27s_displacement_law):

$$ \lambda_\text{max} = \frac{b}{T} $$

where $b$ is the constant

$$ b = 2.8977721 \times 10^{−3} \,\text{Km} \, .$$

Comment: Hey John, why should one care about the black body radiation formula when talking about metal? :-)

Comment: @DanielSank - metal emits radiation as it heats up, same as any other "black" body. There is a reason that there is a [color scale called "hot iron"](http://www.whiterockscience.com/scan2mcnp/images/HotIronBar.jpg)...

Comment: I just think it's worth explaining why the black body law is applicable to something which is certainly not a black body. A reader who is paying attention might get the wrong impression that you're trying to pull the wool over his/her eyes.

Comment: @Floris that comment was also directed at you :-)

Comment: @DanielSank - I think that an attentive reader might have noticed there is a link in the opening sentence to "black body"; in that aritcle, the concepts of "gray" bodies and emissivity are described.

Comment: @Floris Yes, and surely that reader will read the Wikipedia page, see that "gray bodies" are another unrealistic construct with no obvious relevance to real metals, and still wonder why on Earth this answer blithely gives black body formulae with absolutely no mention whatsoever about how *real metals* behave. At least, that's how I'd react :-)

Comment: @DanielSank - I think that John's initial statement "to a good approximation the radiation emitted from a hot piece of steel will be the same as emitted by a black body" is reasonably well accepted physics. Let's leave "tell me more" to OP... Or write another answer that brings out these details. I think John's answer is helpful and sufficient and voted as such. But you are entitled to a different view.

Comment: @Floris I hadn't noticed the change in version 3 of the question. It's much better!

Comment: @DanielSank - peace.

Comment: Actually I agreed with Daniel's comment and added the first line in response to it. I just didn't admit it :-)