# Radiation emitted from a real melted piece of steel [1800C] VS emissivity

Tags: thermal-radiation, metals

In a lot of [questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/200847/what-is-the-wavelength-of-a-hot-metal-when-its-temperature-400-c) I read that a good approximation of the radiation emitted from a hot piece of steel is the black body radiation.

Than I search for the value of the [emissivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emissivity) of molted metal and I [find](http://chrome-extension://oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm/http://www-eng.lbl.gov/~dw/projects/DW4229_LHC_detector_analysis/calculations/emissivity2.pdf) that they are (for a molten Pure Iron) around 0.4 or less.

I know that the emissivity is the ratio between: the radiant exitance of that surface and the radiant exitance of a black body at the same temperature as that surface, so I expect to find a value which is very close to 1 while I get values of about 0.4.

So my question is: Why?

I hope to not forget something important.

Comment: I don't understand the question. The value that you find and the one that is in the document are both 0.4? What's the problem with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing the fact that molten metal emits radiation with a spectrum that is very much like a black body spectrum with the fact that the material has a certain ability to absorb or emit radiation at all at any given wavelength (the emissivity).

When a physicist says something radiates like a black body, they do **not** mean that it has an emissivity of 1.  What they mean is that spectrum of radiation is similar to that of the black body spectrum.

Comment: Are the spectrum of black body and the one of molten metal equal but different from a scale factor?

Comment: More or less.  A black body is a theoretical construct, so when we say they are well approximated by a black body we don't necessarily mean that there is only a scale factor difference.  In this case, when I have done radiation transfer calculations, I always used emissivity x sigma x T^4 as in the Stefan-Boltzmann law and did fine.